# Why isn't cocoapods working on Apple Silicon?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, apple-silicon

On the new m1 mba, I downloaded cocoapods but none of the commands are working, they just crash. I've seen others with the same issue and some said that ticking the 'open with Rosetta' box worked for them but I tried that and it does the exact same thing. Has anyone found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newer developer, but this worked for me on Mac mini M1.

1. As you say, Right click the terminal app -> Get info -> "tick open with Rosetta"
2. Terminal: sudo gem install cocoapods
3. sudo gem install ffi

pod binary should now work fine.

Comment: shouldn't that be the other way around? install ffi in the rosetta terminal and then go back to normal terminal and install cocoapods? thats what worked for me.

also a good thing to note is you need the xcode command line tools to do the above